# Deep clone in TypeScript (preserving types)

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

I need to deep clone an object in TypeScript. This shouldn't be a problem as libraries like Lodash provide appropriate functions for that. However, these seem to discard type information.

```
> var a = new SomeClass();
> a instanceof SomeClass;
< true
> var b = _.cloneDeep(a);
> b instanceof SomeClass;
< false
```

Is there a way to clone objects in TypeScript while preserving this typing information?

Comment: something like `b: typeof a` ?

Comment: Automatically?  No.  You'd need to implement a clone method on the object and its nested objects.

Comment: Preserving Typescript types and preserving SomeClass.prototype is not the same thing. See @Retsam answer and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof. Typescript types are erased at runtime.

Comment: @BrunoGrieder Good call on linking the instanceof MDN documentation; I've edited that into my answer.

Comment: I'm running the same test today (November 2019) with lodash 4.17.15 and it seems that the test is successful, i.e. instanceof returns true in both cases. Did something change in the meantime?

Comment: best solution and easy is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62969704/3913394

Answer (score 24):

Typescript isn't discarding type information here.  In the DefinitelyTyped [lodash.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/lodash/lodash.d.ts) file, you can see that `cloneDeep` is defined as

```
cloneDeep<T>(
    val: T,
    customizer?: (value: any) => any,
    thisArg?: any
) : T
```

Ignoring the arguments we don't care about, it takes a `T` as input, and spits out a `T` as output.  So Typescript isn't losing any type information; it considers the output of `cloneDeep` to be the same type as the input.

You should be able to verify this via your editor: assuming you have some editor that lets you inspect the type of variables or autocompletes methods (which I'd highly recommend, if you don't).

---

Why then is the `typeof` not working as you expect?  It's because the Typescript type information doesn't carry over to runtime.  `instanceof` is a native JS operator, which Typescript doesn't change the behavior of, which you can see by running this snippet:

```js
"use strict";
class A {}

let a = new A();
let b = _.cloneDeep(a);

if (b instanceof A) {
  alert("b is an instance of A");
} else {
  alert("b is not an instance of A");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

The reason that `b instanceof A` is false is that `instanceof` is checking against constructors: `x instanceof A` returns true if the function `A` is a constructor somewhere in x's prototype chain (see the MDN documentation on [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)).  Lodash, however, doesn't use constructors when it clones objects.  It can't.  (How would it know what arguments to pass?)  It creates a plain JS object that has all the methods of the cloned object, but doesn't reproduce it's prototype chain.

Lodash's `clone` (and most of lodash's methods, really) is best used when dealing with raw JS Objects.  If you're using it in conjunction with constructors and `instanceof` checking things get a bit murky.

---

One solution here is to avoid the `instanceof` checking, and do something akin to duck typing; don't check that the object's constructor is a particular function, but check that the object has the properties that you expect it to.

Another solution is, as suggested in the comments, implement a clone method on your class itself, which wouldn't use lodash.

```
class A() {
    clone() {
        var cloned = new A(); //pass appropriate constructor args
        //make other necessary changes to make the state match
        return cloned;
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer, especially the section on TS types getting lost when executing in the browser, needs far more upvotes. Too many people don't understand that distinction.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [Lodash#cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#cloneDeep) utility. Example of use :

```
import * as _ from "lodash";

...

{
    this.cloned = _.cloneDeep(data);
}
```

Comment: The usage of `_.cloneDeep()` as opposed to just the `cloneDeep()` function on it's own is what makes this answer great.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.clonedeep - there is also clonedeep stand-alone

Answer (score 5):

There is an interesting blog post about deep cloning http://blog.soulserv.net/understanding-object-cloning-in-javascript-part-ii/. You can use the author's implementation of the deep cloning `clone()` function:

```
class SomeClass {
    constructor(public test) {

    }
}

let c = new SomeClass("Hey!");
c.test = "Hey!";

console.log(c instanceof SomeClass); // returns true

let cloneC = clone(c, /* resolve circular references */ true);

console.log(cloneC instanceof SomeClass); // returns true
```

[[clone() source code](https://github.com/cronvel/tree-kit/blob/master/lib/clone.js)] [[Complete source code](http://goo.gl/5HxaCk)]

Answer (score 5):

You can create your own deep clone using JSON stringify and parse methods:

```
export function deepClone<T>(obj: T): T {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)) as T;
}
```

Comment: Caution with this: the date objects will be transformed into a string. I.e. its date type will not be kept.

Comment: This is also not consistent in how it works across runtimes and browser environments

Comment: Inline version: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)) as typeof obj`