# Copy values of objects without binding them

Tags: angular

I'd like to copy copy the values of an object (item) to another one (editedItem) to put it into a form and modify it while the original object still is displayed unchanged.

```
<a (click)="editedItem=item">Edit</a>
```

With this approach the two objects are bound, Item changes when the editedItem is modified. Is there a way to just copy the values without binding the objects?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34201483/deep-clone-in-typescript-preserving-types

Comment: This should be more an Angular2-Syntax-Thing than a typescript thing.

Comment: No it shouldn't. I don't see a reason why and it's way too complicated and everyone wants something different.

Answer (score 10):

You can use JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()) if you don't care about the types.

Here is an example:

HTML

```
<a (click)="copy()">Edit</a>
```

TS

```
copy() {
   this.editedItem = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.item))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, would liked to have done this without an extra function, but this works.

```
  <a (click)="toEditItem(item)">Edit</a>

  toEditItem(item) {
      this.editItem= Object.create(item);
  }
```