# How to assign method from class instance to arbitrary object using `Object.assign`

Tags: javascript

```
var foo = {}

class bar {
  fiddle() {
    alert('boo');
  }
} 

Object.assign(foo, new bar());

foo.fiddle();
```

Why doesn't this work? I see `foo.fiddle is not a function`.

In my real-world situation, I know that `fiddle` exists and I just want to copy it into an existing instance of a different class. Something like

```
otherInstance['fiddle'] = bar['fiddle']
```

...but I'm aware that this syntax won't work.

I also find it strange that [this guy's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41272667/19409308) demonstrates `Object.assign` copying a function via:

```
let x = {a: y => y * 2}
let z = Object.assign({}, x)
console.log(z.a(5)); // 10
```

Clarified:

```
let calculator = {double: y => y * 2}
let clone = Object.assign({}, calculator)
alert(clone.double(5)); // 10
```

Modified:

```
let calculator = {double: y => y * 2}
let clone = {}
Object.assign(clone, calculator)
alert(clone.double(5)); // 10
```

But my initial example using a class instance doesn't work, presumably due to the way that prototype is mysteriously related.

### UPDATE

For now, I've decided to convert a bunch of classes into objects so this isn't as much of a nightmare:

```
class foo {
  foodle() {
    console.log('1')
  }
}

const bar = {
  fiddle: () => {
    console.log('2');
  }
}

var test = new foo();
var test2 = Object.create(bar);

Object.assign(test, bar);

test.foodle(); // 1
test.fiddle(); // 2
```

My inner purist would enjoy using classes for all of my components so if there's a solution that allows me to revert the downgrade to objects, I'm all ears!

### UPDATE 2

I'm a dummy, this approach actually does work:

```
var foo = {}

class bar {
  fiddle() {
    alert('boo');
  }
} 

var barInstance = new bar();

foo['fiddle'] = barInstance['fiddle'];

foo.fiddle(); // boo
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44782052/294949, though if it were mine, I might want clone's constructor to run, so I'd consider a static cloning method, that takes a bar instance as a param, creates another, and matches it's state to the param.

Comment: thanks @danh - do you have a recommendation if I don't want to create a new object, and if I don't care about the constructor? Given an existing `targetObject` that may or may not be an instance of an arbitrary class, how do I reassign a known method from an instance of some other class to this object such that I can invoke `targetObject.methodName()`?

Comment: If the fiddle method refers to this.someProp, you'll want that prop, also, right?

Comment: @danh I'm working on known instance methods only at the moment - I've cloned props enough that I'm comfortable handling that separately as needed.

Comment: Why would `otherInstance['fiddle'] = bar['fiddle']` not work?

Comment: thanks @Ry- I'm an idiot, updated. Feel free to drop an answer if you want points otherwise I'll self-answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript prototyping is not that mysterious - class methods are held in the class function's `prototype` property, from where they are inherited by class instance object. Hence one way to assign the method of one class to an instance of another would be to use the pattern

```
otherInstance['fiddle'] = Bar.prototype.fiddle
```

where `Bar` is the name of the class with the `fiddle` method.

You can also find class methods from an instance of the class by looking where it inherits its methods from:

```
otherInstance.fiddle = Object.getPrototypeOf( bar).fiddle
```

or simply let it be inherited as usual:

```
otherInstance.fiddle = bar.fiddle
```

where `bar` is an instance of `Bar` (not the class itself), which necessarily implies that the first object in its prototype chain is `Bar.prototype`.

[`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) could be used instead of assignment to add the method without making it enumerable. Consider using the `class extends` syntax if you want a child class to inherit all the properties of a parent class.

Regarding `Object.assign`: it only assigns enumerable own properties of one object to another. Class methods, however, are neither enumerable nor own properties of class instances.